# How to setup XDebug for PHP7 on Mac?

Tags: macos, homebrew, xdebug, php-7

I've installed PHP 7 on my mac using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) i.e.

```
$ brew install php70
```

Also I want to have the the [XDebug](http://xdebug.org) setup on my machine.

Ideally I would love to have an easy solution like using brew again, but unfortunately it seems there is no such formula exist (at least yet), and the latest package is `homebrew/php/php56-xdebug`.

I thought before start the manual installation, check here to see if there are any other workaround.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: xdebug isn't still finished… you might want to try phpdbg in the meanwhile..

Comment: thanks @bwoebi :) will have look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by Homebrew, [Homebrew/php](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/) tag was deprecated.

So it's not possible to install xdebug through Homebrew anymore. Please use PECL instead: https://xdebug.org/docs/install#pecl

Comment: Worked for me alongside the `php@73` I installed with Homebrew and left unmodified.

Answer (score 14):

First, make sure you're on the version of PHP for which you want Xdebug installed. It needs to be installed separately for each major version (7.0 vs 7.1 vs 7.2). You can check your version using `php -v`.

Then, run `pecl install xdebug`.

Once it's finished installing, you'll see a message like this:

```
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.8/pecl/20170718/xdebug.so'
```

Then go to your php.ini (which you can find by running `php --ini`, and add these two lines to it:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.8/pecl/20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
```

Obviously, change the path to whatever was printed by the pecl xdebug installation.

Comment: Please provide constructive criticism when down-voting.

Comment: On Mac os x Mojave, I was able to get Xdebug installed for PHP 7.3 but I was not able to get that installed for PHP 7.1 and PHP 7.2. Finally, I was able to install using this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/58468660/9185662 - hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 12):

It is available in Homebrew now as `homebrew/php/php71-xdebug`.

Comment: It was removed on march 31, 2018, so no longer working. Not sure how to install it now.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
brew install php71-xdebug
```

and if that doesn't work:

```
brew install --build-from-source php71-xdebug
```

Source: [xdebug install on php70](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2518)

Comment: Seems like it's updated to `homebrew/php/php70-xdebug`

Answer (score 3):

Since Brew is no longer working, you can use pecl to install the debugger.

It's not as good as brew, you may run into dependency problems but it works. Install php with brew, whatever version you want, then use pecl.

```
brew install php
pecl install xdebug
```

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug 2.4.0beta1 already supports PHP 7. Unfortunately the only way for installation for now is to compile it from the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kaloyan

Comment: This is outdated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `brew install php71-xdebug` is not working, and it returns this error:

> Error: No available formula with the name "php71-xdebug"

Try run this command first: `brew tap homebrew/php` .

Comment: It is not a matter of tapping, I still get the error `Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php71-xdebug"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/php is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/php)" fetch --unshallow``

Comment: from https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/

"By 31st March 2018 we will deprecate and archive the Homebrew/php tap. Unfortunately we have been unable to maintain an acceptable, consistent user or contributor experience and CI workload through non-core formula taps in the Homebrew organisation so we are continuing to migrate widely used formulae into Homebrew/core and encourage more niche formulae and options to be supported outside the Homebrew organisation."

Comment: How to install it now?

Comment: @Wouter, recently I also have this problem, do you find solution?