# How to use xdebug with MAC High Sierra standard installation

Tags: xdebug, macos-high-sierra

I reinstalled my macbook with High Sierra (10.13).
It contains Apache/2.4.27 and PHP 7.1.7.

Now I want to activate xdebug.
Please can someone give me some informations, how to do it?

Thanks for help

Comment: My PHP.INI is located at /etc/php.ini
Into php.ini I added:<br><br>

    [xdebug]<br>
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"<br><br>

    xdebug.remote_enable=true<br>
    xdebug.remote_host=localhost<br>
    xdebug.remote_port=9000<br>
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp<br><br>

    xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1<br>
    xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1<br>
    xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1<br><br>

After restarting I can't find xdebug into php info.

Comment: Find an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593880/xdebug-on-macos-10-13-with-php-7?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
```

Then I copied xdebug.so into my extension directory.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Could you explain in more depth what did you do to solve it ? What exactly the command above will do ?

Answer (score 4):

Xdebug altogether with PHP 7.1 comes preinstalled on High Sierra (OS X 10.13.5), you just need to enable it, to do so, paste following in `\etc\php.ini`

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.overload_var_dump=0
```

Note: you might have to create a `php.ini` file by duplicating/renaming this file `\etc\php.ini.default`

---

In addition to above you *might* also need to edit `\etc\apache2\httpd.conf` with following changes:

1. Uncomment this line

   ```
   LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
   ```
2. Paste following at the end

   ```
   <IfModule php7_module>
       AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
       AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

       <IfModule dir_module>
           DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
       </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
   ```