# XDebug not working on MacOS High Sierra : Symbol not found: _xdebug_monitored_function_dtor

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-high-sierra

Before upgrade from MacOs Sierra to High Sierra i had a sweet environment with XDebug running perfectly on PHP.

Now it's not working anymore ; when i start Apache, i get this error on log :

```
    Failed loading /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so, 9): 
Symbol not found: _xdebug_monitored_function_dtor
```

Here is the XDebug codes on php.ini :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Any help is very appreciated, as without debug my work is a lot less effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46623845/6540060

you need to compile your own xdebug.so