# Debug php with Xdebug on mac OS HighSierra

Tags: php, xdebug

I used https://xdebug.org/wizard.php to check my Xdebug status that I installed using below instruction.

But it's seems not working. I tried with NetBeans Xdebug / Sublime Xdebug Clinets and also PHPStrome, but php files are not hit the debug point.

When I check the php content with **I used https://xdebug.org/wizard.php** it's also  displayed

> Xdebug installed : no

Bu I have successfully run all commands and copied the file into xammp's extentions folder.

**php.ini conetnt:**

```
;zend_extension=opcache.so
zend_extension="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so"
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/XAMPP/logs/xdebug.log"
```

[image]

**Tried list:**

- I have tried this one [Xdebug on macOS 10.13 with PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593880/xdebug-on-macos-10-13-with-php-7) but it's not work for me.
- **For @streos (I tried to install xdebug via brew but it's won't work for me):**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xdebug on macOS 10.13 with PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593880/xdebug-on-macos-10-13-with-php-7)

Comment: @SamSwift웃 tried but not work.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use homebrew? I installed via `brew install php72-xdebug` and it works at least for cli. I don't have a server installed so can not say anything about that

Comment: @steros Not work for me. Added image to question.

Comment: Sorry but show a little effort please...

Comment: @steros I'll tried various methods and no luck then post here and still find a solution. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Had problem with permissions, the system didn't let my install xdebug, so I ended up installing another php instead of using the built-in one:

Try [this article](https://medium.com/@romaninsh/install-php-7-2-xdebug-on-macos-high-sierra-with-homebrew-july-2018-d7968fe7e8b8)