# XDebug and macOS High Sierra

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-high-sierra

I think I have done all the configurations people give on the internet about it, but still can't install and make run properly xdebug.so on macOS High Sierra.

The best help so far is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593880/xdebug-on-macos-10-13-with-php-7/46623845#46623845)

But still receiving this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Marcello:compliancy.com marcellopato$ valet php --ini
Failed loading /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_5/extentions/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_5/extentions/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_post_startup_cb
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_5/extentions/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_5/extentions/xdebug.so
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

I tried the [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/wizard), followed each step and here is the code and result:

The 99-xdebug.ini file:

```
;Xdebug
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1;
xdebug.client_port=9003;
xdebug.start_with_request=yes;
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1;
xdebug.remote_enable=1;
xdebug.default.idekey=PHPSTORM;
xdebug.mode=debug;
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Users/marcellopato/xdebugtmp/";
xdebug.show_local_vars=1;
```

And the output of valet php --ini:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Marcello:compliancy.com marcellopato$ valet php --ini
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_post_startup_cb
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

And yes, I have moved the `xdebug.so` extension to the right dir `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so`

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: It is working now!
Followed this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593880/xdebug-on-macos-10-13-with-php-7/46623845#46623845

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xdebug on macOS 10.13 with PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593880/xdebug-on-macos-10-13-with-php-7)